# Just set up Team Foundation Server 2010 and added an existing solution (ASP.NET MVC) to TFS - cannot debug now!

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, tfs

I just added an existing solution to TFS source control.  This was my first time setting up Team Foundation Server 2010 because I realized I had the need to do version control.  I'm an independent developer and I need to have version control on all my projects.

Anyways, so I just set TFS up and it set up fine with no errors.

Here's the issue: an existing project I have been working on built fine and ran fine before I added that directory to TFS source control.  For example, I right click on the start up project and choose Debug -> Start New Instance, and it launched the web browser and ran my project as expected.

But whenever I added it to source control and ran through the same steps, it'll launch the web browser, and it'll have the title page on the web browser title bar for a second, then it'll go away.  I end up with a blank white web browser with nothing in it.  My project builds fine without error.  And even when I click refresh on the web browser, it has the "busy/loading" icon for a FRACTION of a second then stops.

Any ideas?  I made a backup copy of this project before I did this (NOT under source control), and it still runs as expected when I try the same things... it's very frustrating!!!!  Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: When you add a file to TFS it is in read only mode until you made a check-out. Maybe a file that must be overwritten is in read only mode. Try checking-out the entire app. If this works, you should remove something from TFS (an output folder for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only differences you will see between projects in TFS and outside it are:

- (As @hectorct commented) files in TFS that are not checked out will be made read only.
- Some extra information will be added to the Source Control bindings in your Solution files. These won't affect compiling or running the solution, though.

The most likely reason for your compile failing is that you have added non-source (intermediate and output) files to Source Control. These files are generated by the compilation process, and the compile may fail due to them now being read-only.

To fix the problem (after taking a backup just in case), delete all intermediate and output files in your Source Control browser window and check in this change. Specifically, you'll need to remove everything in the obj and bin subdirectories, but there may also be other files depending on your project type. Then rebuild and everything should be ok again.

If that fails, then use a Diff tool that can do a folder difference. Run it over the old (working) and new (broken) code folders to find out where there are differences. It's possible that you have a missing or changed file that is causing a problem, and the problem is nothing to do with TFS as such.